# What is the name and where can I find the manga of Ore-sama Kingdom?

Tags: oresama-kingdom

I watched the ONA of Ore-sama Kingdom, and I know the English name for it, but when I try to look for the manga, it doesn't show. My older sister knows the name but she forgot recently, which makes me also think that it's not Ore-sama Kingdom, that it's another name or another title. I've been dying to read this manga for a long time but never found it.

Ore-sama Kingdom description:
A manga artist (she creates manga books) named Nono transfers to a new school to find 3 handsome "kings" who find out her secret of creating manga books, even though she's still very young (and in high school).

[image: Ore-sama Kingdom]

Answer (score 1):

The name of the manga is the same title as the OVA. It is called Oresama Kingdom (オレ様キングダム, *Kings of My Love*). There is currently no English distributor for the manga nor is there an official English translation of it and the Japanese magazines publishing the series are *Chuchu* and *Ciao*.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kings_of_My_Love